# Checking how lit the player is for a stealth game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, light

So, I'm building a stealth game and while using a shadow buffer with a camera and get pixels has worked, it isn't very effective with the light being at certain angles and it is extremely expensive in Unity. I'm looking for a way to determine how lit the player is through the shader, however, I'm not a programmer and I've never touched shaders. I've been looking for months, but I haven't found a value and everyone is just using triggers, which aren't effect for this game. I'm trying to do something similar to Thief2 or Splinter Cell games. I am aware of raycasts, however, they aren't accurate enough as well.

So, how could I go about determining how lit the player is in order to have that appropriate gradient?

Here is the code that I am using to gather the light so far.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ShadowBufferScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public RenderTexture shadowBuffer;
    Texture2D tex2d;
    public float percentageHidden;
    public float relativeLuminance;

    void Start()
    {   
        tex2d = new Texture2D (shadowBuffer.width, shadowBuffer.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
    }


    void FixedUpdate () 
    {
        tex2d = new Texture2D (shadowBuffer.width, shadowBuffer.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
        RenderTexture.active = shadowBuffer;
        tex2d.ReadPixels (new Rect (0, 0, shadowBuffer.width, shadowBuffer.height), 0, 0);  
        tex2d.Apply ();

        Color shadowBufferColor = tex2d.GetPixel (0, 0);
        relativeLuminance = shadowBufferColor.r * 0.2126f + shadowBufferColor.g * 0.7152f + shadowBufferColor.b * 0.0722f;

        percentageHidden = relativeLuminance * 100;

    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide the specific line of code that you need help with?

Comment: @user1506104 I don't have a specific line of code, since the existing code isn't suitable as it chews up the CPU. I'm looking for something new that is more accurate like in Thief 2 or Splinter Cell games to determine how lit the player is, as is displayed on their light meters in game. I've done triggers, raycasts, and getpixel already, however they are either inadequate or too expensive.

I put up the code that I am using to gather the lights in my question.

Comment: I think this post should show help you with several alternatives https://answers.unity.com/questions/24662/detect-lightshadow-falling-on-object.html

Comment: @AdrianSgro
I've seen that post before and we actually conducted what they did in there. Volumes and Raycasts aren't accurate enough and the RenderTexture is expensive as all hell on the CPU. I've been told a shader could work, however, while I've been researching the shaders, I can't find a value to tell me "This is how lit your character is". :(

Answer (score 0):

I imagine your game as one with a lot of dark areas, with light sources as additional obstacles. I don't know exactly what you mean when talking about triggers, but you could cover your lighted areas with collision zones, which could calculate the distance of the player from the light source into a lighting value that could be sent to the player.

```
// Collision functions based on correct layering (Player/LightingZones)
[RequireComponent(typeof(Collider))]
public class LightingCalculator : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool _entered = false;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (_entered) FindObjectOfType<PlayerController>().LightingValue = CalculateLighting();
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
    {
        _entered = true;
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit(Collision col)
    {
        _entered = false;
    }

    private float CalculateLighting()
    {
        float lighting = 0;
        // Your calculation
        return lighting;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, Triggers are collision zones in Unity. I used Triggers for my prototype and while it is feasible to get a gradient and it was very easy to put in the game, adjusting each trigger's shape became an endless chore on a small level, especially with very large rooms, so I wanted something that was on the player itself. 

I was suggested something in the shader might help. Some value that changes based on light hitting the object, but I haven't found anything like that in Unity. :(

Comment: I haven't seen such a feature in Unity either. The main mindset regarding interaction between GameObjects relies heavily on triggers and collisions (a trigger is just a collision without physical calculation, which would be perfect for this use case weren't it such a mess for you.
I imagine you're working with directional lights mostly? How about simply applying a cone shaped trigger collider and just check for shadow casting?

Comment: I'm actually using spotlights and point lights. Yeah, I've looked for months upon the feature, and the only other option I have heard about is shaders. While researching shaders a little, I haven't found anything to suggest there was a variable accessible through script to determine how much light was hitting it or how the color is changing from the darkest to the lightest. I have some solutions, but neither of them are particularly exciting to me. One solution is to have several triggers/volumes layered with varying values to obtain that gradient I want.

Comment: Or, from what I'm seeing in the scene, the shader becomes darker in shadow (i've never written a shader, please care with me), so what is that variable that affects the object becoming darker in shadow in the shader (if it even is inside of the shader. Again, I don't know).